# Using Sessions in Blade shows blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this in my blade file:

```
@if(Session::has('logged'))
    @include('layouts.usernav')
@else
    @include('layouts.publicnav')
@endif
```

When I run my page, it is just a blank page.

When I change it to look like this:

```
@if(1 == 1)
    @include('layouts.usernav')
@else
    @include('layouts.publicnav')
@endif
```

My page gets displayed. I don't know what I am doing wrong. What would/could be causing this?

Comment: how are you setting the session? can the show the full code?

Comment: Does it also work if you do `@if(false)` to see if `publicnav` is the source of the problem?

Comment: @ThomasKim doing that also gives a blank page.

Comment: It sounds like `layouts.publicnav` is the source of your problem. If you remove everything except just `@include('layouts.publicnav')`, I suspect that it will also show a blank page.

Comment: @ThomasKim Changing `publicnav` to `usernav` works fine.

Comment: Is debug mode enabled for your app? Have you checked the error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: @Bogdan `APP_DEBUG=true`, and the log is empty

Comment: Ok. Then could you please post the contents of `layouts.publicnav`?

Comment: Okay I figured it out, in `publicnav.blade.php` someone put `@extends('layouts.master')` and I guess that isn't allowed.

Comment: I was suspecting it would something like that :). `@extends` is used by [Blade Template Inheritance](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance), so `@include` will not render it.